# Need below div in first position

Tags: html, css

I want Text Left and Text right should come in same line and I can't restructure HTML.And if I use Absolute position I am not sure how it will behave in different devices and  screen size due to yellow area(). Can I give absolute position with reference to parent div(ms-srch-result)

```css
#UpScopeLinkTop{

    display: block;
   float:right;

}
```

```html
<div class="ms-srch-result" id="Result" name="Control">  

   <div id="UpScopeLinkTop" class="ms-srch-upscope-top" style="display:block;width: 700px;">                        
   Text Right 
   </div>

   <div id="ResultCount" class="ms-srch-resultscount">                           
    Text Left                       

   </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** (remove inline styles)

```css
#UpScopeLinkTop{
   display: block;
   float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-srch-result" id="Result" name="Control">  
   <div id="UpScopeLinkTop" class="ms-srch-upscope-top">                        
   Text Right 
   </div>
   <div id="ResultCount" class="ms-srch-resultscount">                           
    Text Left      
   </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:** (flex-box)

```css
.ms-srch-result{
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    width: 200px;
}
.ms-srch-result div{
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-srch-result" id="Result" name="Control">  
   <div id="UpScopeLinkTop" class="ms-srch-upscope-top">                        
   Text Right 
   </div>
   <div id="ResultCount" class="ms-srch-resultscount">                           
    Text Left      
   </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 3:** (flex property)

```css
.ms-srch-result{
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.ms-srch-result div{
 flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-srch-result" id="Result" name="Control">  
   <div id="UpScopeLinkTop" class="ms-srch-upscope-top">                        
   Text Right 
   </div>
   <div id="ResultCount" class="ms-srch-resultscount">                           
    Text Left      
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want Text left first and Test Right second

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in your CSS stylesheet:

```
#UpScopeLinkTop, #ResultCount {
  width: 45%;
}
```

(Adjust the value as you need it)

P.S.: erase the 700px width from the HTML tag of `#UpScopeLinkTop`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need floats. Instead of divs inside the big div, use spans.

```
<div id="thebigdiv">
<span style="display:inline-block";>
Text left
</span>
<span style="display:inline-block";>
Text right
</span>
</div>
```